# Can I change the objet type of an email alert (SP 2007)

Tags: email, alert

I've set up my SharePoint list (MOSS 2007) to send email alerts, and it does.
However, the object type of these alerts is "Sharing Message" and not "Message".
This means that they appear differently in Outlook, and also cause all sorts of havoc elsewhere.

Is there a way to change the object type of the email alerts to the regular message type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to remove this from the alert emails that SharePoint sends.  You can edit the XML templates of the alert emails SharePoint sends, but SharePoint will always attach the alert-related email headers:

```
x-alerttitle: Daily Summary Notification
x-alertid:
 {90F3D082-E0F2-47DB-A12C-4DBEDB73DC08}:{00000000-0001-0001-0001-000000000000}
x-alertweburl: http://developernotifications
x-alertservertype: STS
x-alertwebsoap: http://developernotifications/_vti_bin/alerts.asmx
```

When Outlook sees those headers, it treats the mail item as a SharePoint alert.

The alternative would be to send alerts from a workflow or other method of generating emails.  There isn't anyway to get rid of those for actual SharePoint alerts.

Comment: The one alternative on the header might be to setup Exchange rules to strip out the header: http://scolard.com/wordpress/?p=356.  Don't know if that would actually work, but it is worth a try if you can get your Exchange admins to do it.

Comment: We ended up using a workflow. We were trying to avoid them, mostly out of the lack of time to learn new things. Thanks for the answer.